# parsing html document for anchor tag

Tags: php

say i have

```
<a href="www.myurl/point.html" class="l" style="color:#436DBA;" onclick="return rs(this,'8 Stunning Linguistic Miracles of The Holy Quran | Kinetic Typography 144p (Video Only).mp4');">&raquo; Download MP4 &laquo;</a> - <b>144p (Video Only)</b> - <span> 19.1</span> MB<br />
```

html page like this i wanna parse it with simple dom php parser and i wanna get download mp4 114p 19.1 as out put while i tried this code

```
foreach($displaybody->find('a ') as $element) {
       // echo $element->innertext . '<br/>';
```

it returned me download mp4 only how do i parse remaining values download mp4 114p 19.1 please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `<a>` tag anymore since some of the text you're trying to access isn't inside it anymore, target the document itself and then use `->plaintext`:

```
$html = <<<EOT
<a href="www.myurl/point.html" class="l" style="color:#436DBA;" onclick="return rs(this,'8 Stunning Linguistic Miracles of The Holy Quran | Kinetic Typography 144p (Video Only).mp4');">&raquo; Download MP4 &laquo;</a> - <b>144p (Video Only)</b> - <span> 19.1</span> MB<br />
EOT;

$displaybody = str_get_html($html);
echo $displaybody->plaintext;
```

Here is another way of accessing each row thru `DOMDocument` with xpath:

```
// load the sites html page in DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html_page = file_get_contents('http://www.mohammediatechnologies.in/download/downloadtest.php?name=8KPEiGqDQHg');
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html_page, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$data = array();
// target elements which is inside an anchor and a line break (treat them as each row)
$links = $xpath->query('//*[following-sibling::a and preceding-sibling::br]');

$temp = '';
foreach($links as $link) { // for each rows of the link

    $temp .= $link->textContent . ' '; // get all text contents

    if($link->tagName == 'br') {
        $unit = $xpath->evaluate('string(./preceding-sibling::text()[1])', $link);
        $data[] = $temp . $unit; // push them inside an array
        $temp = '';
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UQ61vK)

Comment: plain text is ok but i have severl bunches of code in that page not only it i mean several anchor tags if i convert plain text all anchor tags will show up in single line how do i deal with it

Comment: @user1735121 but i can't guess with one your working with, i can only work with the one you posted. you need to post what you are working with, at least the site you're scraping anyways

Comment: i am working with this site http://www.mohammediatechnologies.in/download/downloadtest.php?name=8KPEiGqDQHg i wanna sepparate url and then download mp4 480 pixels and 19.1 mb thing in a string

Comment: @user1735121 i have edited my answer, as i suspected, the site's html markup was more complicated than the one you have posted, anyways check out the demo link http://codepad.viper-7.com/UQ61vK